# Can you cook pickled onions?

Tags: onions

Can you cook hot dishes with pickled onions?  I've never seen a recipe which uses them hot, is this just because they don't taste good hot?  What hot dishes might be appropriate to put pickled onions in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been reviewing old family recipes, and I've seen pickled onions called for in some soup, stew, and casserole recipes as an accent; this may or may not be because my foremothers grew and canned loads of onions. It's worth an experiment or two, I think!

Answer (score 9):

This afternoon, I made a veggie/bean chilli. When preparing, I was surprised to notice that we are out of fresh onions. I decided to use a can of pickled onions in the chilli.

60 minutes later and this is my happy finding...that the pickled onions have retained crunch and infused the chilli sauce with the most gorgeous deep and rich sweetness. Pickled onion chilli can rest and infuse a wee bit more.

Comment: Dear Bev, welcome to Seasoned advice. On this site, we expect answers to be to the point, so other people can find information quickly. I shortened your introduction, but left all your relevant information in place. In this form, your answer is better recognizable as useful, so you also get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 2):

Why not?  The salt and acidity will spread to the rest of the dish, and the onions themselves have almost no texture, but you could.  I've seen pickled onions used in baked chicken dishes in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't typically put them *in* a dish but they are spectacular *on* anything that can use a little acidic, crunchy counterpoint. Tacos being the classic example. Also great on a toasted bagel with cream cheese (which is partially hot).

Answer (score 0):

We serve a lamb shank at work which includes as its garnish pickled pearl onions. It's fantastic.